# how to return image in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Currently, I am getting the user details in the response from the server. From that response, I want to encode the image and wants it to display on my front end. currently, this what I am doing:

HTML:   `<img ng-src=data:image/png;base64,{{user_image}}>`

Angularjs:

```
  $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'userimage',
  }).then(function(response) {
     $scope.user_image = response.data;
     var str = _arrayBufferToBase64(response.data.user_image);
  }, function(response) {
    console.error('error.');
});


function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
var binary = '';
var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
var len = bytes.byteLength;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
}
return window.btoa(binary);
```

}

In response, I am getting user details but I don't know how to encode the image. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Just curious as to why the server is returning the actual image, and just its URL

Comment: for the image, I am getting '?' in my response @Mawg

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you assign a base64 encoded string to a scope variable rather than response.data?
I guess, what you really want is:

```
$scope.user_image = _arrayBufferToBase64(response.data.user_image);
```

There is one issue though.
Your haven't specified a response type as 'arraybuffer'.
Please, add that to your request config object:

```
responseType: 'arraybuffer'
```

Comment: I implemented your logic, I am getting the base64 string in my log. But the image is not getting displayed in the browser

Comment: Ok.
Lets make sure, that all simplest things are there.
Is your image really png or it's a jpeg? Is the server really returns us an array buffer and not something else?

Comment: And one more thing - please, enclose a content of ng-src with double quotes since it won't be working properly in your case.
In case if doesn't work still, please take a look at plunker, which I've prepared for a small demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/rfTxKctNHYS2Nl7gzgpx?p=preview

Comment: I am passing png image format. Even the server is returning the array buffer itself. But I don't know where I am going wrong. I will go through the demo and i'll fix it

Comment: Have you enclosed a value of ng-src with double quotes?

Comment: No . Image is not getting displayed . I have 
enclosed the ng-src with double quotes also. @Viacheslavv

Comment: Perhaps, it is on the server side, because demo on plunker works just fine (fetching picture as array buffer and encoding it as base64 string on the client side).
@SRK, can I get a url of an API, which returns picture, which you are trying to show on the front end side?
If yes, we can try to figure out a reason of the issue.

Comment: I solved the issue. It's was some small mistake in the server-side. @ Viacheslav Moskalenko

Comment: Great.
Did my demo on plunker helped you?
Can we mark this question as resolved?

Comment: not much. But I understood the approach and made some changes on my server side.

Comment: Shall we then close this question since you have found an answer and resolved the issue?

Comment: sure we will close it